# Daily summary email of a Sharepoint list with just count values

Tags: list

I have a list on SharePoint 2013. 
(I am going to explain it in a bit detailed fashion as i am not really an expert but an avid user of SP for over 4 years now.)
In this list we have 3 filters (or rather you can call status of a request) that are:

```
Not Started
In Process
In Audit
```

Is there a way I can create a workflow to get an email on a daily basis with nothing but just the count against these 3 statuses from SharePoint itself?

For example, it can be like this:

```
Not Started: 4
In Process: 5
In Audit: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to schedule a workflow to run daily unless you use some third party tools. However, the scenario you mentioned can be accomplished by writing a console application or PowerShell script and scheduling it using windows task scheduler. The other option is to use a timer job.

Answer (score -1):

Write a Sharepoint-Service which is running daily (or even configurable by you)